# Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-broadcastreceiver, android-sms

My app reads incoming SMS. I have implemented receiver, added permission and receiver in Manifest but when SMS is received I get following message in logcat.

> 12-29 13:25:00.081 2030-2044/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial:
>   broadcasting Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
>   flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } from com.android.phone (pid=5234,
>   uid=1001) is not exported from uid 10665 due to receiver
>   com.tatvic.vatsal.test_uninstall_tracking/com.tatvic.lib.uit.SmsReceiver

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    ....>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

SmsReceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            Log.d("MessageReceived", "MessageReceived");
        }
    }
}
```

I have read similar threads on Stackoverflow but nothing helps. I have tested this on Marshmallow OS and have allowed SMS permission.

How can I get received SMS in my app?

**Edit:**

I am able to receive sms in my app when app is opened or is in background after setting `exported = true` in `receiver` tag of `Menifest` file. But when **app is closed** I get the following message in logcat and **cannot receive sms**.

> 12-29 14:28:27.111 2030-2044/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc
>   8428:com.tatvic.vatsal.test_uninstall_tracking/u0a666 for broadcast
>   com.tatvic.vatsal.test_uninstall_tracking/com.tatvic.lib.uit.SmsReceiver

Comment: Post the rest of your manifest. Does `onReceive()` do anything else besides log a message? If so, post that code too. Do you see any exceptions in Logcat? Don't filter the logcat otherwise you might miss something valuable or important.

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1):

Since your receiver is supposed to be invoked outside of your application, you should set its `android:exported` to `true`.

> Set to true if this component is available for use by other applications. Comes from `android:exported` of the `<activity>`, `<receiver>`, `<service>`, or `<provider>` tag.

Comment: Setting exported to true shows this message in logcat now, *I/ActivityManager: Start proc 7308:com.tatvic.vatsal.test_uninstall_tracking/u0a666 for broadcast com.tatvic.vatsal.test_uninstall_tracking/com.tatvic.lib.uit.SmsReceiver*

Comment: @Apurva That's not an error. It just tells that Activity Manager started your application's process, because your broadcast receiver has been enabled. (i.e. it received an broadcast)

Comment: But `onReceive` method of SmsRecevier does not get called. How can I receive callback there even when app is closed.